# Springboot-docker error: cannot invoke "DockerCliInspectResponse.hostConfig()" because "inspectResponse" is null

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I tried to remake a SpringBoot project from scratch, and i met this error `spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning` and nothing that i found online worked. I tried to reinstall docker and now all of my projects wont start. i always get this error in my terminal:

```
Cannot invoke "org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCliInspectResponse.hostConfig()" because "inspectResponse" is null
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DefaultConnectionPorts.isHostNetworkMode(DefaultConnectionPorts.java:56) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DefaultConnectionPorts.<init>(DefaultConnectionPorts.java:47) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DefaultRunningService.<init>(DefaultRunningService.java:55) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DefaultDockerCompose.getRunningServices(DefaultDockerCompose.java:83) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeLifecycleManager.start(DockerComposeLifecycleManager.java:120) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeListener.onApplicationEvent(DockerComposeListener.java:53) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.lifecycle.DockerComposeListener.onApplicationEvent(DockerComposeListener.java:35) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.contextLoaded(EventPublishingRunListener.java:98) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$contextLoaded$4(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:72) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.contextLoaded(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:72) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:416) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at com.example.springboot3jwtauthenticationserver.SpringBoot3JwtAuthenticationServerApplication.main(SpringBoot3JwtAuthenticationServerApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Today I encountered the same problem: [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/37982) on this topic has already been created on GitHub.
This is caused by updating Docker Compose to version 2.23.0; Spring boot does not yet work with this version.

You need to either downgrade docker compose to 2.20.3 or wait for Spring Boot update, I think this will be fixed in next version

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to downgrade docker-compose to 2.20.3 on Mac m1 but I can't, I've tried several ways:

```
brew install docker-compose@2.20.4
```

reinstall docker, but it installs in the latest version which is 2.23.0